# Are the citizens of Milan legally obliged to smile?

Tags: law, italy

Another legal curiosity:

It's been [alleged](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/travel/travel_news/article-2856346/It-illegal-not-smile-Milan-no-donkeys-sleep-bath-Oklahoma-strangest-laws-word.html) that people in Milan have to smile by law. Is this true? If so, what is the legislation?

Comment: +5. That's a very common claim mentioned on almost all news articles.

Comment: I was born in Milan and lived there for 25 years. Never heard of such nonsense before...

Comment: The first claim on that article has been [disproved here](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/27940/may-only-licensed-electricians-change-light-bulbs-in-australia/27943#27943)

Answer (score 7):

In [this 2014 *Corriere della Sera* article](http://www.anarpe.it/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/CORRIEREFC_NAZIONALE_WEB2014_11_15_Page43.pdf), “historian” Andrea Santangelo describes this rule, which he also mentions in his and Lia Celi's book *Mai stati meglio*, as coming from a nineteenth century *Regolamento urbano* (City regulations) imposed by the Austrians then ruling over Milan, due to one “Luigi Fabio”, and never repealed since then.

> Via i mugugni, basta facce smorte, niente musi lunghi: a Milano si sorride per legge. Lo dice un *Regolamento urbano* del periodo austroungarico. «Altri tempi sì, le cose nel frattempo sono cambiate, ma la legge non è mai stata abrogata...» [...] «Erano esonerate – chiosa Santangelo – le persone che partecipavano a funerali, quelle che in ospedale entravano o vi lavoravano». Per gli altri, nessuna scusa a meno di non voler incorrere in una multa pecuniaria. «Abbiamo trovato il riferimento a questa regola in un articolo del “Telegraph” del 2004, ripreso poi in siti che raccolgono stranezze legislative». [...] il regolamento serviva «per dare risalto alla città di Milano stando a quanto sosteneva un consigliere di allora, tale Luigi Fabio (con quei nomi ne abbiamo trovato più d'uno)».
>
> Down with grumbles, no more glumness or long faces: in Milan law compels you to smile. It is prescribed by a *City regulation* from the Austro-Hungarian times. «Other times, indeed, things are different now, but that law was never repealed...» [...] «There were exemptions – Santangelo adds – for people taking part in funerals, for those who entered or worked in hospitals». For everybody else there was no excuse, the alternative being incurring in a fine. «We found this rule mentioned in a 2004 *Telegraph* article, since taken up again in sites collecting legal oddities». [...] this rule was supposed to «give prominence to the city of Milan, according to what a councilman of those times said, a Luigi Fabio (we found more than one with this name)».

One has to be cautious, though, since Santangelo and Celi themselves say, as seen, that they found this rule in a *Telegraph* article, later quoted in sites of legal oddities. And, looking in Google Books for the relevant passage in *Mai stati meglio*, just [a cursory mention can be found](http://tinyurl.com/qguy7b3), apparently without any reference.

Comment: Could you provide a translation of the description?